# React Native: Facebook API /me/picture call returns FACEBOOK_NON_JSON_RESULT

Tags: android, reactjs, facebook-graph-api, react-native, fbsdk

I am writing an android app and using [facebook/react-native-fbsdk](https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk) to retrieve user's facebook profile picture. The call returns this:

`{ FACEBOOK_NON_JSON_RESULT: '����\u0000\u0010JFIF\u0000\u0..}`

Using [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%2Fpicture%3Ffields%3Dredirect%2Curl&version=v2.8) returns correct results (JSON with picture url).

Authentication is done correctly and all other calls return expected data.

Here is my code:

```
const request = new GraphRequest(
  '/me/picture',
  {
    accessToken: 'MY_ACCESS_TOKEN_HERE',
    parameters: {
      fields: {
        string: 'redirect,url'
      }
    }
  },
  (error, result) => {
    console.log(result);
  });

new GraphRequestManager().addRequest(request).start();
```

Any ideas what i can be doing wrong? 
Thanks.

Comment: The default for this endpoint is to issue a redirect to the actual image location on the CDN. If you want JSON, you need to ask for it. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/picture

Comment: @CBroe I thought that `redirect` field should do it (return json instead of cdn image), am i wrong?

Comment: It’s not a field, it is an additional parameter _named_ `redirect`.

Answer (score 1):

```
 // callback function
    const responseInfoCallback = (error, result) => {
        if (error) {
          console.log(error)
          alert('Error fetching data: ' + error.toString());
        } else {
          console.log(result)
          alert('Success fetching data: ' + result.toString());
        }
    }

    // request
    const infoRequest = new GraphRequest(
        '/888284244657368/picture',
        {
          accessToken: accessToken,
          parameters: {
            type: {
                string: 'large'
            },
            redirect:{
                string: 'false'
            }
          }
        },
        responseInfoCallback
    );

    // Start the graph request.
    new GraphRequestManager().addRequest(infoRequest).start()
```